# If I gain pleasure from spanking men, would it be haram to do so?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior

During the spanking, everyone would be fully clothed, and my hand would never touch his buttocks or body at all. I would be spanking him with an object. The man being spanked has agreed to be spanked.

If this is haram, is a punishment prescribed?

I don't have a desire to have any kind of sex with men, but I do want to spank them, for some reason.

Comment: Are you a male or female ? If you are a female, Is the man your mahram ?

Answer (score 2):

Yea it is HARAM. A believer can **not even look** at another human with شهوة (meaning with passion or with aim of obtaining pleasure) so anything that is **more involved** then that is obviously also haram.

Read Surat Nur ayat 30 to 31 https://legacy.quran.com/24/30-31

When the command is to be so cautious to even protect your eyes, how can you justify poking them with an object on the privates?

Answer (score -2):

no it's not until he's your husband it's not haram

Comment: I hope you meant to say as long as he is your husband. As else it is actually haram. Also consider checking [answer].

Comment: Whoever this is - male or female - they said “men”. That‘s plural, more than one.  It sounds like they are giving some kind of S&M service. Men who like to be spanked.... Smh. We muslims imitate the kuffaar more and more every day. Through imitation we  become like them. May Allah save us from our own foolishness!